# Reason for lose responsive of the web page during design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing a ui for a web based application using html5,css3,twitter bootstrap,and javascript.i added all the the bootstrap files to the webpage but now i lost the responsiveness of the web page. what are the main reasons for lose responsiveness of the webpage during development?.

Comment: In what way have you lost responsiveness? Did you include the responsive css file?

Comment: Can you post your code that includes the bootstrap files

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you include the responsive bootstrap file.

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Check the [Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive) for a better understanding of how to implement the responsive design.